# Install apk using root?

Tags: android, su

Is there a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     way of installing an apk from downloads folder without user input on a rooted device?

Comment: The downloads folder of the *Android device* or of the *PC* that it's attached to?

Comment: android device, no pc

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use adb install command to install/update APK silently. Sample code is below

```
public static void InstallAPK(String filename){
    File file = new File(filename); 
    if(file.exists()){
        try {   
            String command;
            command = "adb install -r " + filename;
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command });
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks but how do I specify apk location ?>

Comment: I think you need to learn basics of language before doing something but anyway you can specify apk location by "filename" parameter.

Comment: should i use file format?

Comment: I want to use this  Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
      + "/download/" + "xadb-build.apk")),