# How to set string for uri in android?

Tags: android

How do I make my code use the package name stored in the string (get string from edit text) ? My current code has the package name hard coded:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.android.yourpakgenamehere"); // see here how i used it
    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
    startActivity(uninstallIntent);


pkgname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editme);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you just get the string from the `editText`? Something like this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editme);
String pkgname = editText.getText().toString();
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + pkgname); // use string
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What text are you entering in the editText?

Comment: You need to enter it just like you had it hardcoded: "package:com.example.avd".

Comment: I updated my answer so that the user doesn't need to type in the word package.

Comment: my dawg, I appreciate that shiit

Comment: wonder if you could fix this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325266/install-apk-using-root . I can't figure out how to give file path to downloads folder